# Catching a data bus error exception in kernel mode

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm running Linux on a microblaze in a Virtex 5 chip.  I actually have two chips running the same Linux code, but with different HDL modules in the chip.  I'm writing a driver that I want to be able to detect which chip it's running on and do different things based on that.  During the driver init, I try to read an ID register from an HDL module that exists on one of the chips and not on the other, but on the chip where it doesn't exist, I get a 'Data bus error exception in kernel mode.' Oops.  Is there some way to catch this exception and continue loading my driver?

Here's the code:

```
unsigned region;
unsigned long *res;
unsigned int val;

region = request_mem_region( 0x66000000, 100, NULL );
if ( region ) {
  res = ioremap( 0x66000000, 100 );
  if ( res ) {
    val = ioread32( res ); // exception happens here
    if ( val == REGID1 )
      printk( "we are on chip 1\n" );
    else
      printk( "we are on chip 2\n" );
    iounmap( res );
  }
  release_mem_region( 0x66000000, 100 );
}
```

Comment: it seems the physical address you are using is seems to be wrong. check your processor i/o memory map.  once verify the ranges from cat /proc/iomem

Comment: I said in the question that the address doesn't exist, that's how I'm determining which chip the code is running on.  I need to catch the exception and use the fact that the exception happened as the indicator.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux boot process is pretty unforgiving of memory access violations, especially in kernel code (e.g. a kernel-mode access). Having reviewed the Microblaze code, you cannot "catch" such exceptions as they are immediately fatal (the exception handler will invoke the die() function).

Comment: Then can't I edit the exception handler to not call die()?  Which handler is it?

Comment: Check /arch/microblaze/kernel/exceptions.c, around line 106 in the case for MICROBLAZE_DBUS_EXCEPTION. I suppose you could edit the code to simply return in the way it would in user mode, and then rebuild everything. At least then it shouldn't be fatal...

Answer (score 0):

Facing a similar issue on an ARM64 SoC with a FPGA fabric on the AXI bus, I'd like to share here the solution I found:

The Linux kernel provides (checked on 4.14 kernel) a function called `probe_kernel_read` (and also `probe_kernel_write`), which catches accesses to non-existent FPGA registers (in such case, my FPGA explicitly abort the transfer), along with accesses to non-aligned addresses (not handled in my design).

`probe_kernel_read` doesn't seem to be designed for IOMEM resources, unlike `ioread32` or `readl`, but as my FPGA is mapped as device memory (see ARM [ARM](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0487/latest/arm-architecture-reference-manual-armv8-for-armv8-a-architecture-profile)), this should not be an issue for me. I also checked some transactions directly on the AXI bus and saw no issue. Just be warned that the behavior may depend on the CPU architecture.